# Using jQuery to search a string of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

If I run this code -

```
var html= '<html><head></head><body><div class="bar"></div></body></html>';
console.log($(html).find('div'));
```

I get no results returned, if I run this code -

```
var html= '<html><head></head><body><div><div class="bar"></div></div></body></html>';
console.log($(html).find('div'));
```

Then I get a single result returned - the inner div (`<div class="bar"></div>`). I would have expected the first code snippet to return a single result and the second snippet two results.

Similarly, this code returns no results -

```
var code = $("<div id='foo'>1</div><div id='bar'>2</div>");
console.log(code.find('div'));
```

but this code alerts 'div' twice -

```
var code = $("<div id='foo'>1</div><div id='bar'>2</div>");
code.each(function() {
    alert( this.nodeName );
})
```

Given the result of the second snippet, I would have expected the first code snippet to return two results. Could someone please explain why I'm getting the results I'm getting?

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/GTCuv/

Comment: I changed `console.log` to `alert`, and it alerted `[object Object]`, so it must've found something...

Comment: @Eran Zimmerman: That's because jQuery always returns an object, regardless of the amount of matches found for the selector.

Comment: I presume [object Object] refers to the empty array jQuery returns.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let's split this question into two parts.

First:

```
var html= '<html><head></head><body><div class="bar"></div></body></html>';
console.log($(html).find('div'));
```

and

```
var html= '<html><head></head><body><div><div class="bar"></div></div></body></html>';
console.log($(html).find('div'));
```

do not work because according to the [`jQuery()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM
>   that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use
>   the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert
>   it into the current document. During this process, some browsers
>   filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>`
>   elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative
>   of the original string passed.

- In the first code block, your `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags are getting stripped out, and `<div class="bar"></div>` remains. [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) only searches inside the resulting `<div>`, and cannot find anything.
- In the second code block, your `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags are getting stripped out, and `<div><div class="bar"></div></div>` remains. `find` searches inside the result, and finds a single `<div>`.

---

As for your second part:

```
var code = $("<div id='foo'>1</div><div id='bar'>2</div>");
console.log(code.find('div'));
```

You first give jQuery a string, which it takes and makes into a jQuery object with the two `<div>`'s. Then, `find` searches in each `<div>`, finds nothing and returns no results.

Next, in

```
var code = $("<div id='foo'>1</div><div id='bar'>2</div>");
code.each(function() {
    alert( this.nodeName );
})
```

[`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loops through the jQuery object, taking each of the two created `<div>`'s, and alerts their node name. Therefore, you get two alerts.

Answer (score 20):

the answer is very simple. when you make object using jQuery(html) then it make an hierarchy of nodes, and when you find some node like 'div', it searches in whole hierachy except root elements, and in your first example, you dont have child 'div' nodes. And in your second example you have only one child 'div' node.

so if you keep one extra root node in whole hierarchy, then you can find all your nodes easily. like

```
var html= '<html><head></head><body><div class="bar"></div></body></html>';
console.log($('<div></div>').append(html).find('div'));

var html= '<html><head></head><body><div><div class="bar"></div></div></body></html>';
console.log($('<div></div>').append(html).find('div'));
```

Comment: this is how it should be done. The accepted answer won't work if there are more than 1 root element.

Comment: That'(s the correct answer. An alternative writing that works for me is `$('<div>'+html+'</div>').find('div')`

Answer (score 7):

The simple way is as follows:

Given the string:

```
var html= '<html><head></head><body><div class="bar"></div></body></html>';
```

Search for the div with the class bar:

```
$(html).filter('.bar')
```

Or all divs:

```
$(html).filter('div')
```

Returns the object with the class `bar`

Comment: great! you save my day!

Answer (score 2):

[`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) in the third example, searches children in each matched element. Inside your `div`s there are no `div` children (they don't have any children), so `.find(anything)` will not return any element.

[`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), on the other hand, iterates over the current elements in the set, which does include the `div`s (there are two matched elements - the `div`s).

As for `<html>` in your first example, I'm not sure - perhaps you're not allowed to create a second `<html>` element after the page has loaded. `$('<html><head></head><body><div class="bar"></div></body></html>');` only returns the `div` so `.find` does not return anything.

Comment: jQuery (or more accurately, the browser) removes the `html`, `head` and `body` tags and only keeps the `body` content.