# How do I reset the HTML-fields in a text string, which is just a part of a form? (preferably with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, field, reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I clear all the fields in a variable html content? (preferably with jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240465/how-do-i-clear-all-the-fields-in-a-variable-html-content-preferably-with-jquery)

The answer of this question is **not** find in this question: [Blank out a form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/blank-out-a-form-with-jquery), since I have no form ID to connect to.

I have a text string with a value of a HTML code snippet that has some form elements within, with pre filled values​​. All fields that are found in this code snippet (only) must be cleared/reset.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a form, populate it with your string, and *then* reset it, like so:

```
var myForm = $('<form>').html(your_string).
                find(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').
                val('').removeAttr('checked').removedAttr('selected');
```

Then it's just a matter of accessing the `innerHTML` of `myForm`.

Comment: I can't do that, couse my string is already a part of a form. But it's just not appended to the form in this state.

Comment: @Peter What do you mean it's "already part of a form"?

Comment: I hope you understand that the text string is a variable and not an existing HTML from the page source code.

Comment: @Peter My answer assumes that you have the text string as a variable (that's the `your_string`) part, but it also assumes that that string contains HTML. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes that is the case. It is a string with HTML. And the string is going to be part of an already existing form. In fact, the string is already a bit from the form, that I want to "recycle" and clear up before it reused.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a text string like this:

```
var txt = '<form id="search" action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off"><div><input autocomplete="off" name="q" type="text" value="sample"></div></form>'
var $form = $(txt);

$form[0].reset();

var resetTxt = $form.html();
```

Comment: Well, then use @sdleihssirhc approach to append your html snippet to a form element.