# Clone HTML and remove some nodes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a little tool for live editing using Chrome DevTools, and I have a little button "Save" which grabs the HTML and sends it to server to update the static file (.html) using Ajax. Very simple indeed.

My problem is that I need to filter the HTML code before sending it to the server, I need to remove some nodes and I'm trying to achive this using jQuery, something like this:

```
// I grab all the HTML code
var html = $('<div>').append($('html').clone()).html();
// Now I need to remove some nodes using jQuery
$(html).find('#some-node').remove();
// Send the filtered HTML to server
$.post('url/to/server/blahblahblah');
```

I already tried this [Using jQuery to search a string of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159426/using-jquery-to-search-a-string-of-html) with no success. I can't achieve to use jQuery on my cloned HTML code.

Any idea about how to do this?

Comment: `$('<div>')` ... do you mean `$('div')` ?

Comment: @andymccullough, he is creating the div as a container for the html to be put in. not pulling all of the divs from the html and putting the html in them.

Comment: That's right @smerny ;)

Comment: ah cool, didnt know that is what that done, learn something new everyday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DOM is not a string of HTML. With jQuery, you do DOM manipulation, not string manipulation.

What you're doing is

- cloning the document *(unnecessary because you convert it to HTML anyway)*,
- appending that cloned document to a new `div` for some reason
- converting the content of that `div` to an HTML string
- converting that HTML back to DOM nodes `$(html)` *(so we're back to the first point above)*
- finding and removing an element in those nodes
- *presumably* posting the `html` variable to the server.

Unfortunately, the `html` string has not changed because you manipulated DOM nodes, not  the string.

---

Hopefully you can see above that you're doing all sorts of conversions that have little to do with what you ultimately want.

I don't know wny you'd need to do this, but all you need is to do a `.clone()`, then the `.find().remove()`, then `.html()`

```
var result = $("html").clone(false);

result.find("#some-node").remove();

var html = result.html();
```

Comment: You are right, you have clarified me the concept. I was very close! hahaha. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
var html = $('html').clone();
html.find('#some-node').remove();
```

Comment: Seems like you're guessing. What is being posted to the server?