# How to evaluate a div from a string which is inside .get function of Jquery

Tags: jquery

I evaluated data string inside .get function:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
  var divHtml = $(data).find("#comments-comments").html(); 
})
```

data is a returned page like that:

```
"<  !DOC TYPE html >\r\n\r\n< html ... < / body >\r\n\r\n< / html >"
```

But divHtml doesn't give the div I am interested.

```
var divHtml = $(data).find("#comments-comments").html();    // data is the string above.
```

How can I evaluate #comments-comments div?

Thanks.

Note: I purposefully inserted spaces inside the string since stackoverflow didn't show original string.

Comment: what do you mean by evaluation of divs..?

Comment: _How can I evaluate the divs I want from a string like that?_... **evaluate** would put some light more on it?

Comment: I think the question is: why doesn't `$("<body><div id='comments-comments'><b>hello</b></div></body>").find("#comments-comments").html()` return `<b>hello</b>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking: why doesn't

```
$("<body><div id='comments-comments'><b>hello</b></div></body>").
  find("#comments-comments").html()
```

return

```
"<b>hello</b>"
```

?

jQuery strips out e.g. `<html>` and `<body>`, so the `<div>` is effectively the top-level element. `find` searches for subelements.

Instead you can use `filter` which filters top-level elements:

```
$("<body><div id='comments-comments'><b>hello</b></div></body>").
  filter("#comments-comments").html()
```

More detail here: [Using jQuery to search a string of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159426/using-jquery-to-search-a-string-of-html)

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks. I try to update my page without Ajax solutions which seems to me complex. What do you say about that?

Comment: @user2356198 I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. But I realized what you're doing is probably reinventing something that is built into jQuery – look into how `.load` supports fragments: http://api.jquery.com/load/