# Modify in-memory Jquery element and return it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't this script return the modified element?
The element is indeed changed in the function but not correctly returned.

```
<script>
x = "<div></div><div></div><div></div><p></p>";
function modify (x) {
    $(x).find('div').each(function(index){
        $(this).html('content text'); 
        $(this).addClass('test') ;
    }); 
    return $(x);
}
modify (x);
</script>
```

Comment: That is because when you use `.find()` it will look for child nodes in your element. You will have to wrap your HTML in a wrapper element (like with another `<div>`), and unwrap it when you're done before injecting it into the DOM. Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159426/using-jquery-to-search-a-string-of-html

Comment: How are you determining if it has changed or not? There is nothing in your code which uses/echoes `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` in your each function is not referring to an element of `x`.  You need to declare an variable to represent the x element `this` like so -

```
$(x).find('div').each(function(index, that){
    $(that).html('content text'); 
    $(that).addClass('test') ;
});
```