# How can I get the count of a type of element from data from the server using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been searching for hours and my solution seems right, but it's not working.

The data returned from the server is a partial view, so it contains nothing but html and a script or two.

I've tried searching the children of the data but I always get a count of 0.  Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit_onClick()
    {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Projects/CreateProject",
            cache: false
        }).success(function (data) {
            if ($(data).children('span[class="field-validation-error"]').length == 0) {
                window.location.assign("/Projects/Index");
                alert("New Project request submitted successfully.");
            }
            else {
                $('#modelView').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In the main layout (which this partial view uses) I have these scripts named in the header:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

It should also be noted that when the submit button is clicked, I want to put the partial view being returned from the server in the element named "modelView" located in the main view, if there are validation errors (and I have verified from looking in the data parameter that there is).  I want to redirect if there are no validation errors.  The 'if' statement is always true whether I produce validation errors or not, which means it's not finding any spans with the given type of class.

I thought the selector was wrong at first, but I tried lots of things and the internet seems to say what I have is the correct way.  So I thought there might be another problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It would need to be `.find()` (not `.children()`) but why on earth are you using ajax when you want to redirect?

Comment: Should you specify that `dataType` is "html" in the ajax call ?

Comment: It'd be best to use something like $('span.field-validation-error', data) as your selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing your jQuery to use the find function?

It appears that jQuery (or the browser itself) strips out the `<html>` and `<body>` tags, as mentioned here: [Using jQuery to search a string of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159426/using-jquery-to-search-a-string-of-html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit_onClick()
    {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Projects/CreateProject",
            cache: false
        }).success(function (data) {
            if ($(data).find('span[class="field-validation-error"]').length == 0) {
                window.location.assign("/Projects/Index");
                alert("New Project request submitted successfully.");
            }
            else {
                $('#modelView').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

You could also try:

```
if ($('span[class="field-validation-error"]', $(data)).length == 0) {}
```